# Full calendar wrong end date for basicWeek view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Looking at the following fullcalendar example:

http://fullcalendar.io/views/basicWeek/

If in the console you run:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

You get `2014-06-08` which is right for the week `2014-06-08` -> `2014-06-14` (from sunday to saturday), but if you run:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

You get `2014-06-15` which is the sunday of the next week.

I consider it a bit wrong cause if I have a calendar that shows me a week, I expect the end day be the end day of that week, not the next starting day of the next week.

Is this the expected behaviour? I didn't find any references in the docs.

Anyway, if this is the expected default behaviour, can it be overridden somehow? If I initialise my custom `week` fullcalendar:

```
$('#myWeekCalendar').fullCalendar({
    //...
    ,defaultView: 'basicWeek'
    ,events: {
        url: 'some_url.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: function() {
            return {
                dynamicParam: fn(), // A param returned from a function
                staticParam: 'A static AJAX param'
                // Can't set start and end here, they are overridden by fullcalendar's ones
            }
        }
    }
    //...
});
```

This sends a request to the script `some_url.php` with the following POST data:

```
dynamicParam: // The result of function fn() will go here
staticParam: 'A static AJAX param'
start: // Full calendar will pass $('#myWeekCalendar').fullCalendar('getView').start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
end: // Full calendar will pass $('#myWeekCalendar').fullCalendar('getView').end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Is there a way to pass the correct end day of the current week?

Answer (score 0):

You are right it will give 2014-06-15 which is the sunday of the next week.

But if you print end date as full text

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

you will get 2014-06-15 00:00:00 means midnight 2014-06-14 ( or you can say 2014-06-14 23:59:59).

Solution is either you pass

```
start ($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'))
```

and

```
end ($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'))
```

date with time and check in your database with date time or you have to deduct 1 day from end date.
Like

```
var weekEndDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end
weekEndDate.subtract(1,'days');
```

Comment: But if I pass `start` and `end` in `data` callback, FullCalendar still passes me its internal values it uses with the `basicWeek` view. I cannot override them